# Jquery animate image source replacement left to right and vicersa

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I have an image gallery where I'm replacing the source when clicking next/previous and I want the images to slide when doing so. Something like:

```
 function next(){
    imageNr++;
    image.animate({left: -1000}, 'slow',function() {
        image.attr('src', imageURL + imageNr + imgExt);
    });
    image.animate({right: 1000}, 'slow');
}
```

So when clicking next, the current image should move to the left and bring the next image from the right and the other way around when clicking previous. How can one go about doing that?
Thank you in advance.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sDZ9j/

Comment: you could make a div with overflow:hidden; append() and or prepend() a clone() from the last() and first() img via jQuery and than always animate the one visible and the next() or prev()

Comment: The image tag is already contained in a div with hidden overflow. I am sure there's a simpler way of doing this. The code above slides the image to the left but I can't figure out how to get the next one to slide in from the right hand side.

Comment: show your html and css or even best: creat a fiidle at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I'll do a fiddle in a bit

Comment: Update with jsfiddle but for some reason the image source isn't updated in the fiddle

Comment: I'm sorry, I would like to help. but there was no clicking next/previous, no jquery library, jQuery errors so the script could not do anything. I tried to not change a lot. so you can do the simple way. I just added two "buttons" with a click function left and right (you could use them as next/previous) off course you dont have to. just maybe you try from here http://jsfiddle.net/sDZ9j/14/ (if you don't want to code a gallery, just keep it simple and use one try this http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Comment: That's because I have removed the images off my server :P
I've managed to get it working, see my answer. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working with:

```
    image.animate({'left' : '-1000'},'fast', function(){image.css({'left': '1000px'});});       
    image.attr('src',imageURL + imageNr + imgExt);      
    image.animate({'left' : '0'},'fast');
```

Comment: brilliant, exactly what i needed. In addition. I am doing a reverse animate when the user gets to the end of a gallery. So they sort of know that they are back at the first image. +1 on Q and +1 on A

Comment: That's something that I would love to add to mine. Could you please share the way you've done that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to junkystu, this is the code I used. Note the settimeout which aids the transition (so you dont see the new image leaving the gallery). The figure 95 is based on the animate speed of 100 and is via eye adjustment only. I also added a reverse animation if the user clicked previous image.

I also have thumbnails the user can click on which does not perform any animation. Hence, the `if next else if prev` is skipped when `direction == "none"`

### Old code - don't use this.

```
if (direction == "next")
    image.animate({ 'left': '-1000' }, 100, function () { image.css({ 'left': '1000px' }); });
else if (direction == "prev")
    image.animate({ 'left': '1000' }, 100, function () { image.css({ 'left': '-1000px' }); });

setTimeout(function() {
    image.attr('src', largerImage);
}, 95);

if (direction == "next")
    image.animate({ 'left': '0' }, 100);
else if (direction == "prev")
    image.animate({ 'left': '0' }, 100);
```

Another tip is have the `img` tag inside a `div` where `overflow: hidden;`

### New Code!

Here are my document.ready control event hookups

```
$(document).on("click", ".gallery-thumbnail", function (e)
    {
        var gallery = $(this).closest('.gallery');
        GallerySetFeature(gallery, $(this).attr("data-gallery-id"), "none");
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".gallery-prev", function (e) { GalleryNextPrev(this, e); });
    $(document).on("click", ".gallery-next", function (e) { GalleryNextPrev(this, e); });
    //-- only showing the next/prev controls on hover.
    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".gallery-feature", function (e)
    {
        $(this).find('.gallery-next').removeClass('invisible');
        $(this).find('.gallery-prev').removeClass('invisible');
    });
    $(document).on("mouseleave", ".id-gallery-feature", function (e)
    {
        $(this).find('.gallery-next').addClass('invisible');
        $(this).find('.gallery-prev').addClass('invisible');
    });
```

Here is my function for when the next/prev control is clicked. This handles doing the reverse animation when exceeding direction before first image or after last image.

```
function GalleryNextPrev(control, e)
{
    var gallery = $(control).closest('.gallery');
    var ubound = parseInt(gallery.attr('data-gallery-ubound'));
    var current = parseInt(gallery.attr('data-gallery-currentid'));
    var directionIsNext = $(control).hasClass('gallery-next');

    var newIndex = (directionIsNext ? current + 1 : current - 1);
    if (newIndex > ubound)
    {
        newIndex = 0;
        directionIsNext = false;
    } 
    else if (newIndex < 0)
    {
        newIndex = ubound;
        directionIsNext = true;
    }

    GallerySetFeature(gallery, newIndex, (directionIsNext ? "next" : "prev"));
}
```

Here is my function that does the animation. Note the imagesLoaded function (get http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/)! Oh, plus I add an ajax spinner on top of the image if it does not load in a certain time.

```
var ajaxSpinnerId;
function GallerySetFeature(gallery, thumbIndex, direction)
{
    thumbIndex = parseInt(thumbIndex);
    gallery.attr('data-gallery-currentid', thumbIndex);
    var thumbnail = gallery.find('[data-gallery-id=' + thumbIndex + ']');
    var thumbnailImg = thumbnail.find('img');

    var largerImage = thumbnail.attr('data-gallery-larger');
    var downloadLink = thumbnail.attr('data-gallery-download');
    var thumbTitle = thumbnail.attr('data-gallery-title');

    var feature = $(gallery).find('.gallery-feature');
    var feature_img = $(gallery).find('.gallery-feature img');

    if (direction == "next")
        feature_img.animate({ 'left': '-1000' }, 100, function() { feature_img.css({ 'left': '1000px' }); });
    else if (direction == "prev")
        feature_img.animate({ 'left': '1000' }, 100, function() { feature_img.css({ 'left': '-1000px' }); });


    feature_img.attr('src', largerImage);
    feature_img.attr('width', feature_img.width);
    feature_img.attr('height', feature_img.height);

    //-- IsUndefined is my function, but you know what it is anyway. Just checking Is Undefined!
    if (IsUndefined(ajaxSpinnerId))
    {
        ajaxSpinnerId = setTimeout(function() {
            //-- ajax spinner start
            feature.addClass("gallery-ajax");
        }, 150);
    }

    imagesLoaded(feature_img, function() {
        //-- ajax spinner end
        clearTimeout(ajaxSpinnerId);
        ajaxSpinnerId = undefined;
        feature.removeClass("gallery-ajax");

        if (direction == "next")
            feature_img.animate({ 'left': '0' }, 100);
        else if (direction == "prev")
            feature_img.animate({ 'left': '0' }, 100);
    });

    //-- Just setting labels like title, image size and download link all storted client side as attributes.
    $(gallery).find('.gallery-download').attr('href', downloadLink);
    $(gallery).find('.gallery-title').text(thumbTitle);
    $(gallery).find('.gallery-position').text(thumbIndex + 1);

    //-- because I have little thumbnails the user can directly click on. I put a color border around the thumbnail to indicate the current showing. This works for prev/next image link too.
    gallery.find('.gallery-thumbnail-img-selected').removeClass('gallery-thumbnail-img-selected').addClass('gallery-thumbnail-img');
    thumbnailImg.addClass('gallery-thumbnail-img-selected').removeClass('gallery-thumbnail-img');
}
```